# How do I get Evolution Mail's RSS to work?

Tags: 11.10, evolution

Playing around with Evolution Mail - it has some features that I like. I then downloaded the RSS plugin from the Software Center. Well, it didn't download because it gave me an error.

[image: Evolution RSS]

Simply, how do I install the RSS plugin in 11.10?

Comment: I just wanna click on that Details link so much :P Can you update to reveal what is within please :)

Comment: Here you go: http://i.imgur.com/WCsHR.png

Comment: Can you add the errors that you get into the question in `code tags` please? Looks like a bunch of dependency issues from what I see in the message, but would help more if you could copy and paste all of it into your question.

Comment: This seems to be the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-rss/+bug/873943

They say it's fixed, but mine is not fixed. How do I update the fix?

Comment: I assume you'll have to [enable the "proposed" archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed). After that, apt should be able to access the patched version.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Now I'm sitting with Evolution not notifying me of new mail (like Thunderbird does. When it rains, it pours!)

Comment: @Gonzoza: please write your solution as a new answer and accept it.

Comment: @Gonzoza I have written a Community-wiki answer extracted from the comments above. You could also write your own answer and accept it so it helps future visitors. Also please do open up a new question for the new problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

*Answer gotten from comments:*

> The problem seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-rss/+bug/873943). After [enabling the proposed
>   archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed), `apt` was able to access the patched version.